# Standard or best way to keep alive process started by init.d

Tags: linux, shell, daemon, startup, init.d

I'm looking for a standard way or best practice to keep a daemon started by an `init.d` shell script alive.

Or even better, is there a way to keep it alive directly from `/etc/init.d`?

Specifically, I have a daemon called `dtnd` with and infinite loop that looks for down precess, if there are any, the daemon wake up them again. Also, I use the `start-stop-daemon` tool in order to let the precess by run from a given system user.

I want to run this `dtnd` daemon from startup. In order to achieve this behavior I created a init.d script that "wraps" the `dtnd` file using start, stop and status commands.

I have 2 questions that I will like to solve:

1. Is there a way to achieve **keeping alive some process from init.d** shell script. Is an standard/best way practice?
2. **It's recommended to keep a daemon alive with infinite loop?** I guess it's better to use some tool like daemon to achieve that. It's correct?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Hi Bohemian, You're right. But the process to be run are written in C language so I though that the question fits in stackoverflow. Anyway I will ask it to the guys of Server Fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) library function inside the code of your daemon. You should be aware of [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) (at least to log error conditions). You probably should catch gently the `SIGTERM` signal. Read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Server programs are often [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) based (and it is conceptually an infinite loop). You'll either use en existing event loop library (e.g. [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), [libevent](http://libevent.org/), [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html), ...) or build your own one around a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and study the source code of some existing free software daemon.

Perhaps [dbus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/) is also relevant for your goals (which I don't really understand: what does "looks for down process" exactly means? You could set some limits with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) often invoked thru the `ulimit` bash builtin in some `.bashrc`)

There is also the `@reboot` entry for [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html), but that is not the recommended practice for system daemons (however you could use it in your user crontab file).